# Escritura de arraysList en ficheros de txt java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando escribir un arrayList en un fichero de texto con esta función:

```
    String ruta = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\archivo1.txt";
    File f = new File(ruta);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter escritura = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
        escritura.write(lista.get(i));
        escritura.newLine();

    }
    escritura.close();
}
```

Es un `Arralist` integer que contiene los valores `0,1,2,3,4` y lo que me aparece es esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser el fallo?¿No se puede hacer con bufferedWriter?.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: si ahora lo cambio

Comment: ¿Que es 'Lista'? Lo que devuelva el get tiene un método toString()?

Comment: `Lista` deberia estar en minuscula al no ser una clase. Y como dice Daniel, el get que devuelve?  lo pasas a string primero?

Comment: Es un función donde metes un Arraylist. Y el get debería devolver lo que contiene el Array.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que veo te falta convertir el valor que obtienes mediante el `Lista.get(i)` a `string`, ya que no lo esta tratando como tal puesto que si vemos que son esos simbolos ASCII en valor hexadecimal tenemos que:

```
NUL 00--SOH 01--STX 02--ETX 03--EOT 04--ENQ 05
```

**Edito:** añado el codigo para parsear el `int` a `string` cualquiera de los dos valdrá

```
Integer.toString(Lista.get(i)) o String.valueOf(Lista.get(i))
```

Comment: añadido! @lois6b

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasando cada Integer a String primero:

```
String ruta = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\archivo1.txt";
    File f = new File(ruta);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter escritura = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for(int i=0;i<Lista.size();i++){
        escritura.write(Integer.toString(Lista.get(i)));
        escritura.newLine();

    }
    escritura.close();
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ha funcionado

Comment: @BorjaSanchez si te ha servido, marca la respuesta que consideres oportuna como *aceptada* pulsando el tick de la izq. Y considera dar un *upvote*  ^^ un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que La clase `BufferedWriter` está escribiendo los números como bytes binarios en lugar de como caracteres ASCII.

si cambias el la clase del objeto escritura por un objeto de tipo `Printwriter` este internamente hará el casting de los números a caracteres de forma automática.

```
    String ruta = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\archivo1.txt";
    File f = new File(ruta);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    PrintWriter escritura = new PrintWriter(fw);
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
         escritura.println(lista.get(i));
    }
    escritura.close();
}
```